# Conditional tag for single post of Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a situation where I need to set cookie when a single page of a Custom Taxonomy is executed.

As WordPress not allowing to set cookie from template file I need to use `setcookie` inside `init` action.

Reference : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67074/issues-with-set-cookie

So my function is as follows,

```
function set_location_cookie() {

    // Taxonomy : `store_location`
    if( is_tax( 'store_location' )) {

        die('Yeah. It Worked !!');

        $school = "Some Value";
        setcookie('default_school', $school, time()+3600);
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_location_cookie');
```

I have gone through this document, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax and a post from StackOverflow, [Conditional Tags for Custom Taxonomy in Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712389/conditional-tags-for-custom-taxonomy-in-custom-post-type)

In every situation they are targeting the archive page for Taxonomy or condition with array of locations as follows,

```
is_tax( 'store_location', array('ny', 'tx', 'ga') );
```

Instead of getting all taxonomies in an array, is there any way to detect taxonomy single page easily.

Comment: `is_tax()` is for the archive page. you want it for archive term page or for the single post type page that include terms in this taxonomy?

Comment: I want it for the single page of custom taxonomy

Comment: I don't understand you.. show in which template file? `single.php`? `archive.php`?

Answer (score 0):

To check if post have some terms in some taxonomy you can use `is_object_in_term($post_id, $taxonomy)`

For Example

```
function set_location_cookie() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    // Taxonomy : `store_location`
    if( is_object_in_term($post_id, 'store_location') ) {

        die('Yeah. It Worked !!');

        $school = "Some Value";
        setcookie('default_school', $school, time()+3600);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'set_location_cookie');
```